# jQuery loads the data from PHP but then it disappears, why?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, get

I have searched to see if there is a post similar here and if someone finds it sorry for the duplicate.

So my dilemma is this:

*Given the code below, why it my returned data loading and then disappearing?*

**CSS**

```
#contentbg{
   background-image: url(../images/jp_01.jpg);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: top;
   position: absolute;
   width: 755px;
   height: 629px;
}

#content{
   position: relative;
}
```

**JS**

```
function getHome(){ 
    $.post("php/functions.php?s=home",
     function(data) {
     $('#content').html(data);   
   });
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="contentbg">
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
<ul id="navlist">
     <li id="home"><a href="index.php" onClick="getHome();" title="Home"></a></li>
</ul>
```

**PHP**

```
function displayHome($home){
    if(isset($home)){
        $home = '<img src="images/home.jpg" alt="Home" width="755" height="630" />';
        return $home;
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['s'])) {
    switch ($_GET['s']) {
        case "home": 
            echo displayHome($_GET['s']);
            break;
        }
}
```

I know that the data gets loaded if I alter the JS as seen below:

```
function getHome(){ 
    $.post("php/functions.php?s=home",
     function(html) {
     alert("Data Loaded: " + html);
   });
};
```

Comment: Why are you using POST when you don't send any POST data ad apparently also don't modify anything with your request?

Comment: As noted above, you could just inject this with javascript.

Comment: Everything seems OK. What did Firebug show? Does PHP code respond correctly?

Comment: "Disappearing"? And can you abstract the PHP out of your question? Then demonstrate the issue on jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not cancelling the standard action when you click on the link so what is happening is that you click, the javascript gets executed and then `index.php` gets loaded.

You need to return `false` from your `getHome` function to solve this.

```
function getHome(){ 
   $.post("php/functions.php?s=home",
     function(data) {
     $('#content').html(data);   
   });
   return false;
}
```

As you are using jquery already, you can also get rid of the inline javascript and use a function like:

```
$("#home a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.post("php/functions.php?s=home",
     function(data) {
     $('#content').html(data);   
  });
);
```

That assures as well that the standard event (the click on the link) gets cancelled with the first line.

Comment: @ricbax Strange, it should, but as you are using jquery the second solution I added is nicer anyway (you can remove the javascript from the html).

Comment: Does it seem like your page refreshes once you click the link?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any item with the id `#content` in your HTML, are you sure it exists?

Comment: sorry I forgot to add that important detail in my post

Comment: Can you update your post? Else, can you provide a link to your page?

Comment: Try to temporarily move the `#content` div outside of the `#contentbg` and see if you get any results. I'm not so sure why those are separate divs in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I assume #content is defined in your HTML structure:

```
$('#content').load('php/functions.php?s=home');
```

Also try removing `#content { position: relative; }` for now, just incase the content is "jumping" once loaded into the document

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no "content" div in your html.
Also, use

```
$("#content").load("url");
```

as theres no need to use $.post because no post data is being sent.